# Python for loop to read a JSON file

Tags: python, json, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand a Python for loop that is implemented as below

```
samples= [(objectinstance.get('sample', record['token'])['timestamp'], record) 
            for record in objectinstance.scene]
```

'scene' is a JSON file with list of dictionaries and each dictionary entry refers through values of the token to another JSON file called 'sample' containing 'timestamp' key among other keys.

Although I can roughly understand at a high level, I am not able to decipher how the 'record' is being used here as the output of object's get method. I am thinking this is some sort of list comprehension, but not sure. Can you help understand this and also point me any reference to understand this better? thank you

Comment: `scene` isn't a JSON file, it's just a list of dictionaries. I presume it was created by calling `json.load()` from the JSON file, but once you load it, it's just a normal list.

Comment: What is `objectinstance`? The `scene` attribute suggests that it's an object, but `objectinstance.get()` suggests it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

in non comprehension form it is as below

```
samples = []
for record in objectinstance.scene:
    data = (
              objectinstance.get('sample', record['token'])['timestamp'],
              record
           )
    samples.append(data)
```

`objectinstance.get('sample', record['token'])` this looks like a method, which took two arguments and return a json/dictionary

`{<key1>:<value1>, ... ,'timestmap':<somedata>, ...<keyn>:<valuen>}`

and you are saving record with the `timestamp` value of this call.

it this `objectinstance.get` can be seen as

```
class Tmp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scene = [{'token': 'a'}, {'token':'b'}, {'token':'c'}] 
    def get(self, arg1, arg2):
         # calculation
         
         return result 
     
objectinstance = Tmp()

samples =[]

for record in objectinstance.scene:
    object_instance_data = objectinstance.get('sample', record['token'])
    data = object_instance_data['timestamp']
    samples.append(data)
```

so as you can see, there is method in the object class name `get`, which take 2 arguments, and use them calculation to provide you result in dict/json which as `timestamp` as key value

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the question. They specifically said that they're confused about how the values are being used in the `get()` call.

Comment: @Barmar updated with a explanation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, it is a list comprehension. Schematically, it is something like this:

```
samples = [(timestamp, item) for item in list_of_dicts]
```

The result will be a list of touples, where `(objectinstance.get('sample', record['token'])['timestamp']` is the first entry and `record` is the second.

Moreover, `objectinstance.get('key', default)` gets `'key'` from a dict, if not present returns the `default` value, cf. documentation at [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get%20method#dict.get). The result of the get method seems to be a dict as well, from which the value of key `['timestamp']` is retrieved.

Comment: But `objectinstance` doesn't seem to be a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have a `scene` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you. I think this makes sense to me now. I was not sure of two values being comprehended in list comprehensions.

Comment: Thank you  @Gillanius. With python ref provided this makes sense